# Smart Filter Go Button return error message

Tags: odata, sapui5, abap

I want to show the error message return from odata after clicking the go button of smart filter bar the error . How to get return message and show ?  [errormsg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgFvx.png)
Although I write the logic in search event of smartfilterbar , this logic do while loading the screen . I want to check and show the error message after clicking go button

Here is return code from odata.

```
IF sy-subrc = 0.
  CLEAR et_entityset.

  DATA(lr_msg_cont) = /iwbep/cl_mgw_msg_container=>get_mgw_msg_container( ).


  lr_msg_cont->add_message(
    EXPORTING
      iv_msg_type               =      'E'        " Message Type
      iv_msg_id                 =       '01'           " Message Class
      iv_msg_number             =      '100'            " Message Number
  ).

  RAISE EXCEPTION TYPE /iwbep/cx_mgw_busi_exception
    EXPORTING
      message_container = lr_msg_cont.

ENDIF.
```